# How to conditional filter using UnderscoreJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I just want to pull out an array element based on a condition.

I tried [**Underscore.js**](http://underscorejs.org/) methods like `_.filter` and `_.where` methods, but I cannot get the desired output.

For more clarity,
I don't want a car object where the price is > 80.

I tried with the code below and got an empty array back:

```
var carsArray = [{
    "name": "Record1",
    "bookings": [{
        "price": 50,
        "actualPrice": 70,
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Record2",
    "bookings": [{
        "price": 60,
        "actualPrice": 100,
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Record3",
    "bookings": [{
        "price": 100,
        "actualPrice": 110,
    }]
}];

var availableCars = _.filter(carsArray, function (items) {
    return _.filter(items, function (cars) {
        return(cars.price <= 80);
    });
});
```

Comment: `bookings` is an array, what happens if you have more than one object there? Which one is the price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how to do it with underscorejs

```
var availableCars = _.filter(carsArray, function(car) {
    return _.any(car.bookings, function(booking) {
        return booking.price <= 80; 
    });
});
```

and here's how to do it in es6

```
var availableCars = carsArray.filter(car => car.bookings.some(booking => booking.price <= 80));
```

this ofcourse is if there are multiple bookings possible in a car and at least 1 booking is <= 80 buckeronies

Comment: Happy to help out! Do note: `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.some` can also be used without ES6 and are supported since IE9. You could use them without the array functions! `carsArray.filter(function(car) { return car.bookings.some(function(booking) { return booking.price <= 80; }); });`

Comment: ...and what's the difference between using _.any and _.every in Underscore? In my case, I tested both methods to filter Car objects and they populate the same output.

Comment: because you are filtering against 1 'booking'. Try filtering against 2: one booking with 60, one with 110. `Any` and `Every` work as the names imply: return true if *any* or return true if *every* object matches.

Answer (score 1):

**For multiple elements in the `bookings` array**

If there are multiple elements in the `bookings` array and to check if **any** of the element satisfies the condition [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) can be used.

```
carsArray.filter(car => car.bookings.some(booking => booking.price <= 80));
```

To check if **all** the car booking prices are below 80 [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) can be used.

```
carsArray.filter(car => car.bookings.every(booking => booking.price <= 80));
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
var carsArray = [{
    "name": "Record1",
    "bookings": [{
        "price": 50,
        "actualPrice": 70,
    }, {
        "price": 40,
        "actualPrice": 70
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Record2",
    "bookings": [{
        "price": 60,
        "actualPrice": 100,
    }, {
        "price": 90,
        "actualPrice": 160
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Record3",
    "bookings": [{
        "price": 100,
        "actualPrice": 110,
    }, {
        "price": 120,
        "actualPrice": 200
    }]
}];

var atLeastOne = carsArray.filter(car => car.bookings.some(booking => booking.price <= 80));
var allCars = carsArray.filter(car => car.bookings.every(booking => booking.price <= 80));

document.getElementById('some').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(atLeastOne, 0, 4);
document.getElementById('every').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(allCars, 0, 4);
```

```html
<strong>For any of the car bookings less than or equal to 80</strong>
<pre id="some"></pre>

<hr />
<strong>For all of the car bookings less than or equal to 80</strong>
<pre id="every"></pre>
```

---

**For single element in `bookings` array**

You can use JavaScript [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as follow.

```
carsArray.filter(car => car.bookings[0].price <= 80);
```

```js
var carsArray = [{
    "name": "Record1",
    "bookings": [{
        "price": 50,
        "actualPrice": 70,
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Record2",
    "bookings": [{
        "price": 60,
        "actualPrice": 100,
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Record3",
    "bookings": [{
        "price": 100,
        "actualPrice": 110,
    }]
}];

var filteredArr = carsArray.filter(car => car.bookings[0].price <= 80);

console.log(filteredArr);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filteredArr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

---

If there is only a single element in the `bookings` array, the format of the data can be changed as

```
var carsArray = [{
    "name": "Record1",
    "bookings": {
        "price": 50,
        "actualPrice": 70,
    }
}, {
    "name": "Record2",
    "bookings": {
        "price": 60,
        "actualPrice": 100,
    }
}, {
    "name": "Record3",
    "bookings": {
        "price": 100,
        "actualPrice": 110,
    }
}];

var filteredArr = carsArray.filter(car => car.bookings.price <= 80);
```

Comment: Hello Tushar,There will be more than one entry in bookings array.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
var availableCars = _.filter(carsArray, function(car){
  return _.every(car.bookings, function(booking) {
    return booking.price <= 80;
  });
});
```

I'm assuming each car can have more than one booking and that you want a car **only** if none of its booking was more than 80.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd chip in with something that is closer to the requirement

***I don't want a car object where the price is > 80***

```
function expensiveBooking(booking){
    return booking.price > 80;
}

function carHasExpensiveBooking(car){
    return _.some(car.bookings, expensiveBooking);
}

var result = _.reject(carsArray, carHasExpensiveBooking);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var availableCars = _.filter(carsArray, function(item){
    return (item.bookings.price <= 80);
    });
});
```

Comment: Still the array is empty but it works with _.every / _.any methods